# DropDownListFor not working with nested list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor, html-select

My DropDownListFor not bind selected item.

This is correct model:

```
public class DeliveryOrderModel
{
    public BoxInfo Boxes { get; set; }

    public class BoxInfo
    {
        public long? CountryID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in this model problem:

```
public class DeliveryOrderModel
{
    public List<BoxInfo> Boxes { get; set; }

    public class BoxInfo
    {
        public long? CountryID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is SelectItems

```
var Countries = new SelectList(new[] 
{   
    new { CountryID = 1, Text = "Name1" }, 
    new { CountryID = 2, Text = "Name2" }, 
    new { CountryID = 3, Text = "Name3" } 
} ,"CountryID","Text");
```

This dropdown work with first model:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Boxes.CountryID, Model.Boxes.Countries)
```

And this is trouble dropdown:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Boxes[0].CountryID, Model.Boxes[0].Countries)
```

Comment: OK - understand now. I think there may be an issue with the model and that you need to separate the country list from the box info. Is your root model a box and a country ID for that box? Let me know and I can offer a small restructing thought.

Comment: Problem can be solved by this step:
`(model.Countries.SingleOrDefault( v => v.Value == model.CountryID.ToString())).Selected = true;`

Comment: OK Cool. Still think the country list should not be part of your model though but a separate viewlist; that should give automatic selection of country from model country ID.

Answer (score 0):

First thought - SelectList is a collection, not an array, so you may need something like:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Boxes.First().CountryID,
    Model.Boxes.First().Countries)
```

May also need a lamda expresson for the `.First`

**ADDITION**

Model might be like

```
public class DeliveryOrderModel
 {
 public List<BoxInfo> Boxes { get; set; }

 public class BoxInfo
 {
     publix Box myBox  { get; set; }
     public long? CountryID { get; set; }        
 }
}
```

CountryList becomes a separate and independent SelectList ViewModel.
And finally the view

```
    Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Boxes[0].CountryID, Countries)
```

Or a ForEach to iterate through the boxes, or ...

OK?

Comment: No differencies between Boxes[0] and Boxes.First()

Comment: @FreeVice See addition above.